# How to implement constrained shuffling of a sequence

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, shuffle

I had a need for simulating the output of a multithreaded scenario, where multiple threads are processing in parallel an ordered sequence. The output is not ordered any more, but not completely shuffled either. I thought that implementing such a shuffling should be trivial, and wouldn't take more than 10-20 minutes. But it proved much trickier than I though. So now after many-many hours of struggling with the problem, and refining the requirements along the way, I have managed to produce a complex implementation with a non-optimal statistical behavior. Lets start by stating the requirements:

1) The method should return a deferred `IEnumerable`, so that sequences of infinite length could be shuffled.
2) There should be a hard upper limit at the random displacement of each individual element.
3) The distribution of displacements should be approximately flat. For example a sequence of 100 elements shuffled with `maxDisplacement = 2` should have ~20 elements displaced by -2, ~20 by -1, ~20 not displaced, ~20 by +1 and ~20 by +2.
4) The shuffling should be random. Different invocations of the method should normally return a differently shuffled sequence.

Example of input and output. A sequence of 20 elements is shuffled with `maxDisplacement = 5`.

> Input: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
>   Output: 0, 3, 2, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8, 12, 9, 11, 13, 10, 15, 16, 19, 14, 17, 18

Below is my best attempt so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ConstrainedShuffle<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Random random, int maxDisplacement)
{
    if (maxDisplacement < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDisplacement));
    random = random ?? new Random();
    var buffer = new SortedDictionary<int, TSource>();

    IEnumerable<(int Index, int BufferMaxIndex)> EnumerateInternal()
    {
        int index = -1;
        int bufferMaxIndex = -1;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            bufferMaxIndex++;
            buffer.Add(bufferMaxIndex, item);
            if (bufferMaxIndex >= maxDisplacement)
            {
                // Start yielding when buffer has maxDisplacement + 1 elements
                index++;
                yield return (index, bufferMaxIndex);
            }
        }
        while (buffer.Count > 0) // Yield what is left in the buffer
        {
            while (!buffer.ContainsKey(bufferMaxIndex)) bufferMaxIndex--;
            index++;
            yield return (index, bufferMaxIndex);
        }
    }

    foreach (var (index, bufferMaxIndex) in EnumerateInternal())
    {
        int bufferMinIndex = buffer.First().Key;
        int selectedKey;
        if (index - bufferMinIndex >= maxDisplacement)
        {
            // Forced picking of the earliest element
            selectedKey = bufferMinIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            // Pick an element randomly (favoring earlier elements)
            int bufferRange = bufferMaxIndex - bufferMinIndex + 1;
            while (true)
            {
                var biasedRandom = Math.Pow(random.NextDouble(), 2.0);
                var randomIndex = (int)(biasedRandom * bufferRange);
                selectedKey = bufferMinIndex + randomIndex;
                if (buffer.ContainsKey(selectedKey)) break;
            }
        }
        yield return buffer[selectedKey];
        buffer.Remove(selectedKey);
    }
}
```

This implementation fails to comply with the 3rd requirement. The distribution of displacements is a strange curve, with a peak at the maximum positive displacement (exaggerated greatly for large values of `maxDisplacement`). Here is the distribution of a 1,000,000 elements sequence, shuffled with `maxDisplacement = 10`:

```
-10: 44,188
 -9: 44,199
 -8: 43,701
 -7: 43,360
 -6: 43,134
 -5: 43,112
 -4: 42,870
 -3: 43,628
 -2: 44,170
 -1: 45,479
  0: 50,029
 +1: 58,611
 +2: 67,077
 +3: 71,663
 +4: 70,175
 +5: 62,914
 +6: 52,835
 +7: 40,974
 +8: 30,553
 +9: 21,210
+10: 36,118
```

> Negative/Positive displacements: 437,841 / 512,130

It is possible that I am missing a simpler solution to this problem.

---

**Update:** I implemented a solution based on [Jim Mischel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56959845/11178549), and it works great! The shuffling is symmetrical regarding positive and negative displacements, there are no visible seams at the points where the shuffled chunks are connected, and the distribution of displacements is almost flat (smaller displacements are slightly favored, but I am OK with that). It is also very fast.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ConstrainedShuffle_Probabilistic<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Random random, int maxDisplacement)
{
    if (maxDisplacement < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDisplacement));
    random = random ?? new Random();
    int chunkSize = Math.Max(100, maxDisplacement);
    int seamSize = maxDisplacement;
    int chunkSizePlus = chunkSize + 2 * seamSize;
    var indexes = new List<int>(chunkSizePlus);
    var chunk = new List<TSource>(chunkSizePlus + seamSize);
    int chunkOffset = 0;
    int indexesOffset = 0;
    bool firstShuffle = true;
    int index = -1;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        index++;
        chunk.Add(item);
        indexes.Add(index);
        if (indexes.Count >= chunkSizePlus)
        {
            if (firstShuffle)
            {
                ShuffleIndexes(0, indexes.Count - seamSize);
            }
            else
            {
                ShuffleIndexes(seamSize, seamSize + chunkSize);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++)
            {
                yield return chunk[indexes[i] - chunkOffset];
            }
            if (!firstShuffle)
            {
                chunk.RemoveRange(0, chunkSize);
                chunkOffset += chunkSize;
            }
            indexes.RemoveRange(0, chunkSize);
            indexesOffset += chunkSize;
            firstShuffle = false;
        }
    }
    if (firstShuffle)
    {
        ShuffleIndexes(0, indexes.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        ShuffleIndexes(seamSize, indexes.Count);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
    {
        yield return chunk[indexes[i] - chunkOffset];
    }

    void ShuffleIndexes(int suffleFrom, int suffleToExclusive)
    {
        var range = Enumerable
            .Range(suffleFrom, suffleToExclusive - suffleFrom).ToList();
        Shuffle(range);
        foreach (var i in range)
        {
            int index1 = indexes[i];
            int randomFrom = Math.Max(0, index1 - indexesOffset - maxDisplacement);
            int randomToExclusive = Math.Min(indexes.Count,
                index1 - indexesOffset + maxDisplacement + 1);
            int selectedIndex;
            int collisions = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                selectedIndex = random.Next(randomFrom, randomToExclusive);
                int index2 = indexes[selectedIndex];
                if (Math.Abs(i + indexesOffset - index2) <= maxDisplacement) break;
                collisions++;
                if (collisions >= 20) // Average collisions is < 1
                {
                    selectedIndex = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (selectedIndex != i && selectedIndex != -1)
            {
                var temp = indexes[i];
                indexes[i] = indexes[selectedIndex];
                indexes[selectedIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    void Shuffle(List<int> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            int j = random.Next(i, list.Count);
            if (i == j) continue;
            var temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample distribution of displacements. A sequence of 1,000,000 elements is shuffled with `maxDisplacement = 1000`, and then the displacements are grouped and the average occurrences are shown:

```
[-1000..-801]: 443
 [-800..-601]: 466
 [-600..-401]: 496
 [-400..-201]: 525
   [-200..-1]: 553
          [0]: 542
   [+1..+200]: 563
 [+201..+400]: 546
 [+401..+600]: 514
 [+601..+800]: 475
[+801..+1000]: 418
```

Execution time: 450 msec

Comment: Is it correct to say that one part of this method populates a collection and the other part shuffles it? Does the part that shuffles care how the collection was populated? It might be easier to follow if you separate the two. Maybe the second part is all we need to see. If the part that populates the collection isn't part of this, I'd delete it, or at least separate the two functions. That will make it easier to tell which parts of this someone actually needs to read.

Comment: @ScottHannen my implementation uses an internal buffer holding at maximum `maxDisplacement * 2 + 1` elements. This buffer is used to pick and yield random elements of the source. The `EnumerateInternal` method exists to simplify the enumeration of the source, and finally of what is left in the buffer. Before adding this inner method my implementation had a lot more code, because the logic for processing the elements of the source was duplicated for the leftovers of the buffer.

Comment: Also my implementation is statistically flawed, and I am not sure that it is fixable. Maybe I need to scrap it altogether and start fresh with something completely different.

Comment: I have a hunch that it has something to do with iterating from start to finish. Maybe displacing earlier elements constrains how much later elements can be displaced.

Comment: @ScottHannen I think you are right. Currently I favor earlier elements as candidates for picking, which is expressed by calling `Math.Pow(random.NextDouble(), 2.0)`. Otherwise many earlier elements were not picked randomly, and so they were forcefully yielded when the hard limit was reached. But this seems like a hack, and didn't solve the problem completely anyway.

Comment: It's an interesting problem. I'm not an algorithm guy at all. But if the intent is to "randomize" while ensuring that any given item moves no more than a certain distance, that seems confusing since every time you move one you limit the options for the others.

Comment: @ScottHannen maybe the requirement of solving this as an deferred enumerable is too much. I should probably try to solve it for static arrays or lists, by swapping elements around until the result is satisfying enough.

Comment: I think that before creating the algorithm it could be beneficial to manually create a smaller result set that matches your desired output, just to see if it's possible. I suspect that it isn't. If you can't create it manually then you can't create it randomly. http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2018/06/21/IntegersAndEstimates.html (That doesn't look relevant, but it is.)

Comment: @ScottHannen trivial example: 1, 2, 3 -> 2, 1, 3. One element displaced +1, one -1, and one stayed in its initial place. But in this case the output 1, 2, 3 would also be valid, because this is how randomness works. The statistical properties of the algorithm can only be deduced after many samplings.

Comment: With your requirements, not using the random generator and always returning a fixed permutation of the input will satisfy these requirements. You need a fourth condition, something about the randomness of the shuffle, because it's fairly easy to devise a way to always "shuffle" any input satisfying points 1 to 3, but always returning the same output for the same input sequence.

Comment: I think that the evenness of the distribution will be a function of the number of elements and the maximum allowed displacement. You can even it out perfectly with three elements and a maximum of displacement of two. But try it with 100 elements and maximum displacement of 4. Is possible to shuffle it and even out the distribution of displacement, even manually? I don't think it is. I think you'll discover limitations which are a function of those inputs.

Comment: @V0ldek good point. I updated my question to add a requirement about randomness.

Comment: @ScottHannen having a perfectly flat distribution is not a requirement. Take coin-flipping as an analogy. A [fair coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin) is expected to land heads half of the time, but if you flip it many times the actual distribution is rarely exactly 50%-50%. And obviously it is impossible to have a perfect 50%-50% distribution if you flip it an odd number of times. This doesn't invalidate the fairness of the coin!

Comment: Correct, but even the overall "evenness" that you get from multiple coin tosses might not be achievable, or if they are then it might not be random.. Your requirements were for ~20. I'm not saying that I'm anywhere near certain, though.

Comment: @ScottHannen I am not an expert at probabilities either, but currently I hold the optimistic assumption that there is nothing theoretically wrong with my requirements. So I don't feel an urge to construct practical examples of flat distributions for every possible combination of sequence-length and max-displacement. I may be wrong, and I may have created a monster problem like [doubling the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube), but for the time being I have no real reason to refrain from being an optimist. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea that should work on a finite array.

Given a max displacement of 2:

- index 0 can be moved to index 1 or 2
- index 1 can be moved to index 0, 2, or 3
- index 2 can be moved to index 0, 1, 3, or 4
- etc
- index 8 can be moved to 6, 7, or 9
- index 9 can be moved to 7 or 8

So here's my idea. Let's use an array of 10 items:

```
working = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
available = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  // make a copy of the initial array
avail_count = 10
```

Now do the following until avail_count < 2:

1. Select an item at random from the `available` array.
2. Select a random number between -2 and +2, inclusive (except in the special cases of 0, 1, 8, and 9, where your range is limited).
3. Add your offset to the number you selected. That gives you the index with which you will swap the item you selected in step 1. (This won't always work, see below.)
4. Swap those two items in the `working` array.
5. In the `available` array, remove the two swapped items by replacing with the last item and reducing the count.

Let me illustrate with an example.

1. Pick a random number between 0 and 9, inclusive, and pull that item from the `available` array. Say the random number is 5. The item at `available[5]` is 5.
2. Pick a random offset. Say you picked -2.
3. Add -2 to 5, resulting in 3: the index to swap with.
4. Swap those two items, resulting in: `working = [0,1,2,5,4,3,6,7,8,9]`

Step 5, remove 3 and 5 from the `available` array and decrease the count accordingly:

```
available = [0,1,2,3,4,9,6,7,8]  count = 9
available = [0,1,2,8,4,9,6,7]    count = 8
```

The next iteration will illustrate the problem I alluded to in step #3.

1. Pick a random number between 0 and 7, inclusive. Say we picked 2. The item there is 2.
2. Pick a random offset. Say we picked 1.
3. Add 1 to 2, giving 3. Now we have a problem. The item at `working[3]` is 5. We can't swap 2 with 5, because doiong so would result in a displacement of 3, which is higher than your stated max-displacement.

I can think of two ways to solve this problem. The first is easy. If the item at `working[index]` isn't equal to `index`, then assume that you can't swap: treat it as though the random offset was 0. Just remove the first index from the `available` array, reduce the count, and go on.

The other way is to build an array of all the eligible items in the range `-max_displacement..+max_displacement`, and randomly select one. This has the drawback of being O(max_displacement*2), but will work.

Whatever the case, if you continue this until `count < 2`, then you will have shuffled the array, maintaining your displacement rule. Whether this will give you the distribution of displacements that you want is another question. I'd have to code it up and give it a whirl to determine that.

Now, making it work on a stream? My first try would be to do it in large-ish chunks. Would have to give that more thought.

Comment: The method you describe was one of my first attempts. The easy method of dealing with the problem has the disappointing characteristic that you can safely predict a later element in the shuffled sequence as soon as you get an earlier displaced element (because pairs of elements are swapped once). Didn't like it. The hard method was ... hard. My brain started hurting too much and I gave up. But I may give it a second try because it promises that the distribution will be at least balanced, regarding the number of positive and negative displacements.

Comment: I managed to implement your idea. It was not easy, but I am happy with the result. I updated my question with the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: Precompute all possible options for a buffer of size n? e.g. for -1,0,+1 and a buffer of 3 you get [0,1,2],[0,2,1],[1,0,2],[1,0,3 carry 2] assuming no carry forward from before. So ...

```
 [0,1,2]         has a total shift of 0
 [0,2,1]         has a total shift of 2
 [1,0,2]         has a total shift of 2
 [1,0,3] carry 2 has a total shift of 3
```

Do the same thing for the case when you have a carry forward (you have two states you can be in at the start, one with no carry forward, one with a carry forward and the carry forward must land in the first cell in this simplified case).

So now you can assign probabilities to each pattern to meet the flat distribution and can pick one at random accordingly. This outputs all N next values and then you take the carry and start again.

Clearly for something greater than -1,0,1 you will have far more possibilities and you will also potentially have more items to carry forward.

Now, can you simplify this? Maybe put the choices in a directed graph using relative offsets? Loop the graph back when it repeats. Assign probabilities to each branch to get the flat distribution. Maybe turn it into a finite state machine.

Bonus points: create a finite state machine that implements the algorithm but doesn't know the probabilities for transitions. Now use machine learning to train it to get a flat distribution by assigning probabilities to transitions.

*I would have made this a comment since it's not a direct answer but it grew too long*;

Comment: This sounds promising, although it is clearly far beyond the capabilities of my poor brain to implement!